# Akka: How to work with returned Json feed?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, spray-json

I get a Json feed back from a remote third party API in this way:

```
val myjson: Future[HttpResponse] = http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = encodedUri))

myjson onComplete {
   case Success(response) => sender ! WrappedResponse(response.entity.toJson)
   case Failure...
}
```

case class WrappedResponse(response: JsValue)

The `HttpResponse.entity` contains my json feed. Is it possible marshall and unmarshall this Json feed or only parts of it?

One of the problem is that when I send it back wrapped the json in a case class I get something:

```
Error:(38, 78) Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for akka.http.scaladsl.model.ResponseEntity
        case Success(response) => sender ! WrappedResponse(response.entity.toJson)
```

How can I "marshall" Json itself?

**UPDATE**

I finally get to unmarshall the data first in this way:

```
val responseData = sendHttpRequest(encodedUrl)
      val bodyAsString = responseData.flatMap { response => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String] }

      bodyAsString onComplete {
        case Success(body) => sender ! WrappedResponse(body)
        case Failure(response) => response
      }
```

and in my marshaller:

```
trait MyJsonMarshaller extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {

  implicit val titleDeedResponseFormat = jsonFormat1(WrappedResponse.apply)

}
```

but the "re-apply" marshalling is not working

Answer (score 0):

Sure! This is untested and adapted from code in my own project, but you could do something like:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshal

val myResponse: Future[HttpResponse] = http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = encodedUri))

val jsonFut = myResponse.flatMap {
   case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, entity, _) =>
     Unmarshal(entity).to[JsObject]
   case other =>
     logger.debug(s"Failed response: $other")
     throw new Exception(other.toString())
}.recover {
  // ... error handling
}
```

In this case, you would deal with the `JsObject` result in an ad hoc way. But if you define `JsonFormat` instances for domain model classes, you could unmarshall directly to domain objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-apply" marshalling? Are you experiencing a compiler error?